# Virtualbox bridged guest O/S cannot connect to gateway (OpenVPN issue)

Tags: virtualbox, openvpn

Strange things are happening since a few days.

I have a VirtualBox 6.1.4 server, and two virtually identical guests with respect to networking: they are both bridged, one is at 192.168.0.2, the other at 0.3, the server itself is at 0.9. My gateway is at 0.1.

From the server I can ping the guest at 0.3 but **not** the other one. When both guests are running they can both ping the whole network, but guest 0.2 can **not** ping the gateway. When I start only the 0.2 guest it can see the gateway just fine.

What happened, and how can I repair this?

Thanks!

---

**UPDATE**

ip route show on the working system:
[image]

but on the other system:
[image]

The system that cannot see the gateway is an OpenVPN client, the other is the OpenVPN server.  The real question seems to be: how can I prevent that traffic with destination 192.168.0.1 gets lost somehow in OpenVPN?

Comment: If you say identical, are they perhaps cloned? By copying the files? They may have conflicting MAC addresses.

Comment: I guess I found it, or part of it: when I stop OpenVPN the gateway can be reached again. So this may turn out to be an OpenVPN question. I'll be back!

Comment: MAC addresses are different, both have a static IP address as indicated, everything works, except for the gateway. I noticed one strange line in the routing list, I'll update the question.